# To arrange the hierarchy in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table dbo.Hierarchy that contains the following data:

```
  Level1 Level2 Level3 Level4 Level5 Level6 Level7 Level8 Level9 Level10
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    a      b      c      d      e      f      g      h      i      j
    k      l      m      n      o
```

There are a total of 10 levels and any item can have hierarchy upto any level. In the above data a is the parent of b, b is the parent of c and so on. j and o are the last levels in their respective hierarchies. How can I get the output in the below format:

```
  Name   ParentName   LevelID
-------------------------------
   a         NULL        1
   b         a           2
   j         i           10
   k         NULL        1
   l         k           2
   o         n           5
```

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: I tried using the below format:
SELECT Level1  AS Name, Level2 AS ParentName, 1 AS LevelID
WHERE Level2 IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT Level2 AS Name, Level3 AS ParentName, 2 AS LevelID
WHERE Level3 IS NOT NULL
and so on...

This will give me the desired result set but I am looking for any generic approach.

Comment: I think the table structure should change.For the above we need a table with just 2/3 columns
* Name
* Level
* ParentLevel
Then it could be easy.

Comment: Check about [`UNPIVOT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: @uvgoyal As Jithin suggests, you would probably be better off if your table had just 2 columns - name and level.

Comment: We need to have 3 columns and that is what I am trying to create. 2 columns will not solve the purpose as there is one-to-one mapping between parent and child and having only the Name & Level will not uniquely define the relationship.

Comment: @uvgoyal Valid point. I missed that when going through your question. You would need a column with same value for all the 10 values in 1 row of your current structure to uniquely identify the relationship I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like (untested)

```
with t(L1,L2,L3,L4,L5,L6,L7,L8,L9,L10) as (
    values ('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j')
         , ('k','l','m','n','o',null,null,null,null,null)
) 
select x.* 
from t 
cross apply ( 
   values (L1,null,1),(L2,L1,2),(L3,L2,3),(L4,L3,4),(L5,L4,5)
        , (L6,L5,6),(L7,L6,7),(L8,L7,8),(L9,L8,9),(L10,L9,10)) x (name, parentname, levelid) 
where name is not null
```

Comment: `cross apply` sqlservers implementation of `cross join lateral`. It can be thought of as a mean to transpose columns to rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
;with base as
(select *, row_number() over (order by level1) rn from tbl),

 src as
(
 select 
 valname as name, 
 cast(substring(colname,6,len(colname)) as int) as level, 
 rn from
(select * from base) s
unpivot
(
 valname
 for colname in ([level1],[level2],[level3],[level4],[level5],[level6],[level7], [level8],[level9],[level10])
) u
),

cte as
(select * from src
 where level = 1
 union all
 select s.* from src s
 inner join cte c on s.level = c.level + 1 and s.rn = c.rn)

select distinct s.name, t.name parentname, s.level levelid from 
cte s
left join cte t on s.rn = t.rn and s.level = t.level + 1
```

Breakdown:

1. CTE **base** is used to generate row number as a derived column. We will use this column to keep track of which values belong to which row. This will help in uniquely mapping children to their parents.
2. CTE **src** is where we transform the table from this denormalised structure to a normalised one. Using `UNPIVOT`, we reduce the data set to 3 columns - `name`, `level` and the row number `rn`.
3. CTE **cte** is a recursive CTE that we use to get all possible combinations of parents and children (including immediate parents as well as ancestors).
4. Finally, we `LEFT JOIN` **cte** to itself on the condition that row number is same on both sides of the join i.e. the values belong to same record from the base table, and also that the value from the right side is the immediate ancestor (parent) of the value on the left side.

[Demo](http://rextester.com/DSISM24607)

The huge mass of code above can be avoided, if you were to choose a normalised structure for your table. I would suggest something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl
(ID int, --Keep track of values that are related to each other
 Name varchar(100), --Name
 Level int --The level for a particular value
)
```

With this proposed structure, all you would need is the recursive CTE (`cte` from the above code) and the left join to get the parent-child data. The beauty of this approach is that you can extend it to any number of levels that you like, without having to hard-code the level numbers.

[Demo](http://rextester.com/DKY93135)

Comment: No. What I'm saying is that rather than store parent name, the data can be inserted in proposed format, and then results can be obtained as shown in the demo link.

Comment: I removed my comment after I realised that id is sort of a chain-id. It will work fine for the sample data provided, but assuming that a node can have several children, how do you derive parent for a given node?

Comment: I see in the comment that it is a 1-1 relationship, i.e. a chain. You can ignore my question.

Comment: @Lennart Nevertheless, it is a valid concern. While I based my suggestion on the sample data and the assumption that it is 1-1, your initial comment of storing parent name in the table would make life much easier if the relation is not 1-1.

Comment: @shree.part18: Slight change is required in your code. Instead of "cast(substring(colname,6,len(colname)) as int) as level", "cast(substring(colname,14,len(colname)) as int) as level" will work. I am getting the required results. Thanks!!